# Variadic-templated class: support void without specializing the whole class?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a class:

```
template <typename ...Arguments>
class CSignalConnection
{
public:
    CSignalConnection(std::function<void(Arguments...)> target) : m_target(target) {}

    void invoke(Arguments&&... args) const
    {
        m_target(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(Arguments...)> m_target;
};
```

I want to be able to declare `CSignalConnection<void>` and call `invoke` with no arguments. And I want to avoid specializing, i. e. duplicating the whole class, when I only have a couple void-incompatible methods (like `invoke` here which should be declared with 0 arguments). I have a couple more classes like this so I hate to write everything twice (and edit in two places).

One idea I have is to write both void and non-void `invoke` overloads and disable one with SFINAE, but I don't know how to actually implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CSignalConnection<>` will make the `Arguments` pack empty.  The following works for me

```
void f() {
    std::cout << "hello world\n";
}

int main () {    {
    CSignalConnection<> cs{&f};
    cs.invoke();
}
```

However, since you have no type deduction this is a misuse of forwarding, you'll need to make `invoke()` deduce the types of its arguments to get real universal references (forwarding references)

```
template <typename ...Arguments>
class CSignalConnection {
  public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    void invoke(Ts&&... args) const
    {
        m_target(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
    //... rest of the class omitted ...
};
```

Comment: Your `invoke` is no different from mine.

Comment: So. The solution to my actual question is here, but how do I achieve perfect forwarding?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe yes it is, let me wrap it in a class to make it more obvious.

Comment: [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) may be helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like it will be!